# How can I combine affine transformations into one matrix?

Tags: matrices, transformation, image-processing

[image]

So from what I understand from this picture, the box is stretched to twice its width. And it is then flipped from the x-axis. And then it is rotated 30 degrees anticlockwise.

So these three transformations are **Scaling**, then **Reflection** then **Rotation**.

How am I supposed to go about answering this problem. Also, it says which **homogenous** 2d matrix, this is confusing for me because when you convert cartesian coordinates to homogenous coordinates, you are going from 2d - 3d. This question is saying homogenous but it is a purely 2d transformation, I find this confusing.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Final matrices:

The scaling matrix is... $$\begin{bmatrix}2& 0& 0\\ 0& 1 & 0\\0& 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
The translation matrix is... $$\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 3\\ 0& 1 & -1\\0& 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
And the Rotation matrix is...$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(30) & -\sin(30) & 0\\ \sin(30) & \cos(30) & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is that right? Now you simply matrix multiply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't represent such a transform by a $2 \times 2$ matrix, since such a matrix represents a *linear* mapping of the two-dimensional plane (or an affine mapping of the one-dimensional line), and will thus always map $(0,0)$ to $(0,0)$.

So you'll need to use a $3 \times 3$ matrix, since you need to represent *affine* mappings. If you represent the point $[x,y]$ as the vector $(x,y,1)^T$, then the matrix $$
T_{u,v} = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & u \\
  0 & 1 & v \\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
represents the *translation* in the direction $[u,v]$, i.e. $$
  T_{u,v} [x,y] = T_{u,v}(x,y,1)^T = (x+u,y+v,1) = [x+u,y+v] \text{.}
$$

To find the representation of a *linear* mapping as a $3 \times 3$ matrix, simply take the $2\times 2$ matrix that represents the mapping in euclidean two-dimensional space, and embedd it into a $3 \times 3$ matrix like this $$
\begin{pmatrix}
  M & 0 \\
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{.}
$$
For example, you'd represent a rotation around the origin (which is a linear mapping) as $$
  R_\varphi = \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi & 0 \\
  \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{.}
$$
You can use normal matrix multiplication to combine the matrix representation of affice mappings - for example, to rotate around the point $[u,v]$, compute the product matrix $$
  T_{u,v} R_\varphi T_{-u,-v} \text{,}
$$
which simply says "shift the center of the rotation to the origin, rotate around the origin and shift back".

Comment: So in that case wouldnt my 2x2 scaling matrix be $$\begin{bmatrix}2& 0& 0\\ 0& 1& 0\\0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$$ in 3x3

Comment: Depends. If you scale first, then yes, but you'll need to rotate by 120 degrees, not 30, because your scaling matrix scales the $x$-Axis. Personally, I'd put the $2$ into the second column of the second row, i.e. scale the $y$-Axis, then rotate by 30 degrees counter-clockwise (i.e., mathematically positive), and then translate. But that's just my preference, there are multiple ways to do this..

Comment: @Clay On second thought, make that "scale, translate, rotate", i.e. rotate last. Then, all the parameters of these three transforms can be read directly from the picture. If you rotate first, you'll have to put a little bit of work into computing the translation vector.

Comment: What about the reflection? You say "scale translate rotate" but when I look at the picture, what I see is "scale, translate, reflect on x axis, then rotate 30 degrees." I'm having trouble seeing it any other way.

Comment: I view that not as a reflection, but simply as a translation. In "scale, translate, rotate", the translation I have in mind moves the box 1 unit down and 3 units to the right. But you can view it as a reflection too, but then you one matrix more that you must multiply...

Comment: ahhhh ofcourse... Genius. Okay I'm going to put the matrices in an edit to see if they're right

Comment: Ok I edited the question

Comment: @Clay Looks fine, although you want want to either write the angle in radians, or at least mark them as being states in degrees by adding a degree sign.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the all the help.

Comment: @Clay When multiplying, be carefull to use to correct order. Remember that $AB$ means applying $B$ *first*, and $A$ second if you're working with column vectors (which you do, otherwise your matrixes would need to be transposed).

Comment: So you're saying to Scale -> Translate -> Rotate. S, T and R, respectively, the multiplication would be R(TS)?

Comment: @Clay Yes. You may drop the parenthesis, btw - matrix multiplication is associative, i.e. $A(BC) = (AB)C$.